# Delete all files from A subdirectory of ALL subdirectories in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have the directory structure

```
c:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
c:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
c:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
...
```

I want to delete `Temporary Internet Files\*.*` from all `c:\users\` `x|y|z...` `\...`

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

Edit :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad c:\users\') do (
del /q "c:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\"*.*
)
```

Comment: so.. not possible without knowing x,y,z?

Comment: sure it's possible. Check my EDIT

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /F "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /s ^| find "ProfileImagePath" ') do (
        call pushd "%%~b\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files" > nul 2> nul 
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            cd
            echo rmdir . /s /q 
            popd
        )
    )
```

This will search for location of the users profiles. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: +1 but perhaps `popd` should go outside the `if` branch? Also, why `call pushd` and not just `pushd`?

Comment: @AndriyM, no, `popd` is only necessary if `pushd` can change to the desired folder. If it can not change the current folder, `popd` can interfere with the rest of the script (if it uses `pushd` for another reason)

Comment: @AndriyM, the reason for `call pushd` is the usage of environment variable references in the profile path definitions. Without the `call` they are not correctly replaced with their values.